# Kendo UI MVC Masked Textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface, kendo-ui

I'm using the new Masked Textbox from Kendo UI for MVC and it actually works fine and binds into model without problems. One feature I didn't get automatically is the ability to press "Enter" key and submit my form.

Other textbox I use (Kendo().AutoComplete()) works fine with the "Enter" key.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox()
    .Name("PhoneNumber")
    .Mask("(999) 000-0000"))
```

Comment: What are you asking for help with?

Comment: Is there a clean way with Kendo to enable the "Enter" key on Masked Textbox or I add a function to keypress in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from the Kendo forum. The feature is not currently available but they gave a javascript workaround on keypress.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/masked-textbox-with-enter-key-submit-form